# pytube import Youtube: missing package

Tags: python

my Code:

```py
from pytube import Youtube
from sys import argv


link = input("put the link input:")
yt = Youtube[link]

print("Title: ", yt.Title)

yd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

yd.download(r'C:\Users\adam6\OneDrive\Desktop\video')
```

ERROR:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Youtube' from 'pytube' (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube_*init*_.py)

---

1. I checked and **init**.py > is there at `C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube`

```
PS C:\Users\adam> pip install pytube3 --upgrade                                                Requirement already satisfied: pytube3 in c:\users\adam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\adam\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pytube3) (4.3.0)
```

2. using Visual Studio Code to run it.

```
PS C:\Users\adam\OneDrive\Desktop\study\python> python --version
Python 3.10.6
PS C:\Users\adam\OneDrive\Desktop\study\python>
```

A. yes i needed to change it to YouTube

ran into another error:

I build mine from start to bottom, and ran into to another issue, here are the code and steps. hope this helps if someone is building there

Code:

from pytube import YouTube from sys import argv

link = argv[1] yt = YouTube(link)

yd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

yd.download(r'C:/Users/adam/OneDrive/Desktop/video')

got error:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone

STEPS:

python -m pip install --upgrade pytube

python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/pytube/pytube

Ran as ADMIN.

worked fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290952/python3-8-pytube-importerror-cannot-import-name-youtube-from-pytube-unknow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290952/python3-8-pytube-importerror-cannot-import-name-youtube-from-pytube-unknow)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3.8 pytube ImportError: cannot import name 'YouTube' from 'pytube' (unknown location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290952/python3-8-pytube-importerror-cannot-import-name-youtube-from-pytube-unknow)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a typo in `from pytube import Youtube`.

`Youtube` should be `YouTube`. So you can try:

```
from pytube import YouTube
```

and :

```
yt = YouTube(link)
```

reference : https://pytube.io/en/latest/

Comment: Perfect! thanks everyone this is closed